# How to make Stylecop to ignore a project in a solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts, project, stylecop, solution

When I choose Tools > Run Style Cop (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>) it runs StyleCop over all projects, even the one which are set to not build in the current solution configuration.

How to use this hotkey to check only the projects that I want?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out the **Disable stylecop analysis for specific projects within solution** question at [Disable stylecop analysis for specific projects within solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473481/disable-stylecop-analysis-for-specific-projects-within-solution) as I think this is what you are looking for.

To summarise, I managed to get this to work by adding the RulesEnabledByDefault global settings property to a Settings.StyleCop file which I put in the root folder of each project I did not want to be included in the StyleCop analysis.

```
<StyleCopSettings Version="105">
  <GlobalSettings>
    <BooleanProperty Name="RulesEnabledByDefault">False</BooleanProperty>
  </GlobalSettings>
</StyleCopSettings>
```

If you make use of merged settings files, you may also have to include the MergeSettingsFiles global settings property. For example:

```
<StyleCopSettings Version="105">
  <GlobalSettings>
    <StringProperty Name="MergeSettingsFiles">NoMerge</StringProperty>
    <BooleanProperty Name="RulesEnabledByDefault">False</BooleanProperty>
  </GlobalSettings>
</StyleCopSettings>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope, that option isn't available in any shipped StyleCop version.  If you want it added, either request the feature at http://stylecop.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic or go ahead and add it yourself.