# Disable stylecop analysis for specific projects within solution

Tags: c#, stylecop

Is there a way to easily stop StyleCop warnings from being displayed within specific projects in a solution. Or, more pointedly, a way to select which projects StyleCop analysis should be performed on by Visual Studio?

We have a solution with 9 projects in it. There are only 2 projects that I actually want to see StyleCop warnings for, so I've created `StyleCop.Settings` files within those project root directories. This means that, for the rest of the projects, the default rule set is applied and I get a screen full of warnings every time I open a class.

The only way I can think to remove these warnings is to add another `StyleCop.Settings` file a folder level above with all the rules switched off and set merge options on the specific Settings files I am interested in to not merge with this parent file. This just feels wrong though. Is there a cleaner option or is this my only one?

UPDATE: I'm specifically looking for a way to stop the warnings from appearing within Visual Studio. I've added a `Settings.StyleCop` file to the solution folder and disabled all the rules. I run StyleCop analysis across one of my test projects and there are no errors reported. However, opening a test class reveals a raft of StyleCop warnings, which I want to suppress. Could this be the StyleCop for ReSharper plugin? I have a code cleanup profile created and have disabled certain rules within there but that doesn't appear to make any difference within my test classes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make Stylecop to ignore a project in a solution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926993/how-to-make-stylecop-to-ignore-a-project-in-a-solution)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Please have a look at [File Lists](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20File%20Lists&referringTitle=Documentation) configuration - they allow to disable rules by default per project:

> **Enabled Or Disabled By Default**
>
> In addition, a new setting allows you to determine whether rules
>   should be enabled or disabled by default. This can be set either at
>   the project level or at the SourceFileList level. For example, here’s
>   how you would set up a project with all rules disabled by default, and
>   only two rules explicitly enabled:

```
<StyleCopSettings Version="4.3">
    <GlobalSettings>
        <BooleanProperty Name="RulesEnabledByDefault">False</BooleanProperty>
    </GlobalSettings>
```

Comment: Epic. Thanks Alexander. I've added a settings file in the solution folder containing that single global setting, and it's removed all the warnings from the projects I'm not interested in covering with StyleCop.

Comment: Agreed.  Reading the linked File Lists documentation, this is epic.  I am excited to do the inverse - a solution-level file with rules enabled and a (few) project-level file(s) with rules disabled by default as shown.  Whether to disable by default higher up then enable where needed further down...or enable by default higher up then disable where needed further down would seem to hinge on the project ratio involved - projects to analyze vs. projects not to analyze.