# Disable rule for documentation header in StyleCop for tests project

Tags: stylecop

I have CC.Net with integrated StyleCop in it. Is it possible to disable rule, which requires documentation header for methods, only for tests projects, for example. Or for the projects, which names match the specified pattern. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a stylecop topic than a CCNet one, but look at the following topic in stack overflow :
[Disable stylecop analysis for specific projects within solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473481/disable-stylecop-analysis-for-specific-projects-within-solution)

I think that should do it